# Axios issue with the URL having strong #

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api, axios

If am passing URl in axios like

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/#abc?pt=1

Then am getting the only url in my network like

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/

If anyone can help with the correct way of passing URL with # will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The format of your URL is incorrect:

You have: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/#abc?pt=1`

But it should be: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?pt=1#abc`

A URL fragment must be the last component of a URL.

Comment: See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.5